# CSS Transition is ignored by media query

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, transition

```css
.burger-button {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out 1s
}

.burger-button span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #fff
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
  .burger-button {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<body>

  <a href="#" id="jQ-burger">
    <div class="burger-button">
      <span></span><span></span><span></span>
    </div>
  </a>

</body>

</html>
```

I use this CSS code to display a burger butten when viewport size is getting smaler. If i resize my window on desktop, the transition (transition: opacity 1s ease-out 1s) is ignored. The Button appears without delay and without transition. But if I use developer tools and turn off/on opactiy:1 then it works. Any idea?

Comment: Could you post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can test your code.  Why do you have two duration values in your `transition` property?

Comment: I put more code, the example is new. transition: opacity 1s ease-out 1s = 1s Duration and 1s Delay. If I do that here in the stackoverflow editor, it works. However, if I do that in my original page code, the transition is ignored when resizing the window. It is played when turning on/off opacity in the Dev Tools. Happens in FF and Chrome.